# IEEEtran conference template author section: space, font and line breaking

Tags: fonts, spacing, line-breaking, ieeetran, author

I am using the IEEE conference template in Overleaf. https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-conference-template-example/nsncsyjfmpxy

I got a few problems setting the author section.

1. The space between the first name and last name of the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th authors disappears.
2. Some words become italicized automatically.
3. How to start a new line at the end of the first `\authorblockN`?
   If I put a `\\` at the end of the `\authorblockN` I would get an error when compiling.

In addition, what are the functions of `\authorblockN` and `\authorblockA`, and what's the difference between them in IEEE?

The following code is what I have in Overleaf. And, the picture is the corresponding result. I tried to find the answer in an IEEE class guide https://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/files/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf but I still don't get it. If there are some other helpful resources, please advise! I appreciate any suggestions.

```
\author{
\authorblockN{JJ S\authorrefmark{^1}, J S\authorrefmark{^1}, J 
D\authorrefmark{^2}, A S\authorrefmark{^1^2}}
\authorblockA{\authorrefmark{^1}Mechanical Engineering Department, 
University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, Michigan\\
Email: js@umich.edu}
\authorblockA{\authorrefmark{^2}Energy Institute\\
University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, Michigan\\}
}
\maketitle
```

[image: the corresponding result]

Comment: `^1`can only be used in math mode. You should recieve an error message about this. In fact, the outpu you show looks a lot like a pdf that was produced by code that results in an error message.

Comment: Remove the `^` (Use `1` instead of `^`). Replace `\authorrefmark` with `\IEEEauthorrefmark`, replace `\authorblockA` with `\IEEEauthorblockA` and `\authorblockN` with `\IEEEauthorblockN`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the more recent version of the user manual that can be found for example here: https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran